# Android CalendarProvider-Event custom column

Tags: android-calendar, customcolumn

What is the best way to extend the CalendarProvider-database by a new column? I want to store some extra data for every Calendar-Event. I tried to use CalendarContract.ExtendedProperties but this is only for use by sync adapters and therefore an exception occurs.